# Manejo de Arrays en Javascript (Añadir valor, borrar valor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, javascript-objeto

Tengo un array en el que voy añadiendo valores de la siguiente manera:

```
var miarray = [];
if ($('#micheckbox'+valor).is(':checked')) {
  miarray.push(valor);
} else {
  delete miarray[valor];
}
```

Lo qu ehago es tener una lista de checkbox en función de los cuales el valor de dicho checkbox se añade o se quita del array, para luego convertir ese array en un string usando `var string = miarray.join(',');` de este modo me queda el string separando por comas dichos elementos.

Lo que necesito es que cuando el checkbox esté unchecked elimine el valor del mismo del array y posteriormente me genere la string sin contener el valor no deseado

El caso es que el `miarray.push(valor)` funciona, pero el delete no lo  hace. He probado intentar localizar el key de ese valor pero tampoco me sale, lo he consultado aquí:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/findIndex
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258077/how-to-find-index-of-an-object-by-key-and-value-in-an-javascript-array

Pero esas soluciones no me funcionan a mi

Comment: podrias colocar tu codigo completo y el resultado esperado para poder ayudarte mejor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probarlo con el objeto Set() ya que te permite agregar y remover objetos de manera fácil. Set permite agregar valores únicos, por lo cual para eliminarlos sólo debes indicar el valor en cuestión, de la siguiente manera:

```
var checkedValues = new Set();
if ($('#micheckbox'+valor).is(':checked')) {
  checkedValues.add(valor);
} else {
  checkedValues.delete(valor);
}
```

Y posteriormente para devolverlo como string, puede probar lo siguiente:

```
var miarray = Array.from(checkedValues);
miarray.join();
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Espero haber entendido su pregunta, si lo que desea es obtener el valor de un "**input**" que está en "**check**", entonces le agregamos una clase para poder recorrerlos y posteriormente agregar el evento "**change**", el cual se ejecuta cuando nota un cambio en el elemento, en este caso, se ejecutará cada vez que marquemos o desmarquemos la casilla.

```js
var miarray = [];

$('.mis-inputs-check').each(function() {

  $(this).change(function() {

    var mi_input = $(this);

    if(mi_input.is(':checked')) {
        // Agrega un nuevo elemento al array
        miarray.push(mi_input.val());
    } else {
        // Retorna el índice del elemento que quieres eliminar
        var idx_valor = miarray.indexOf(mi_input.val());
        // Eliminar el elemento
        miarray.splice(idx_valor, 1);
    }

    console.log(miarray);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><input class="mis-inputs-check" type="checkbox" value="valor-1">Valor-1</li>
            <li><input class="mis-inputs-check" type="checkbox" value="valor-2">Valor-2</li>
            <li><input class="mis-inputs-check" type="checkbox" value="valor-3">Valor-3</li>
            <li><input class="mis-inputs-check" type="checkbox" value="valor-4">Valor-4</li>
            <li><input class="mis-inputs-check" type="checkbox" value="valor-5">Valor-5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Con esto logra añadir un elemento cuando se marque la casilla y eliminarlo cuando se desmarca. De "**click**" en ejecutar y posteriormente a "**Página completa**" para apreciar mejor los resultados.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba el siguiente código:

Primero, captura el índice del array según su valor.
Luego, con "splice" elimina el índice del vector, los parámetros son:

1. Primer parámetro del splice: índice del vector
2. Segundo parámetro del splice: cantidad de elementos del array a eliminar a partir del índice declarado en el primer parámetro.

**Código**

```
var miarray = [];
var indice;

if ($('#micheckbox'+valor).is(':checked')) {
  miarray.push(valor);
} else {
  indice = miarray.indexOf(valor);
  miarray.splice(indice,1);
}
```

**Nota:**
Con utilizas "delete", **eliminas solo el valor del índice**, pero con "splice" **eliminas el índice completo.**